# NSMenu detecting fullscreen menu bar visible

Tags: swift, popover, menubar

I'm writing a popover menu bar app for OSX. I need the app to not open when the menu bar is hidden (fullscreen app is active).

Here is the code:

```
func showPopover(sender: AnyObject?){
    eventMonitor?.start()
    if let button = statusItem.button {
        if NSMenu.menuBarVisible() {
            popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `NSMenu.menuBarVisible()` function seems to always return `true`, even when there is an app in fullscreen mode. Does anyone know why or have an alternate solution?

The documentation states that `NSMenu.menuBarVisible()`:

"Determines whether the menu bar is visible for this application.  Users cannot access the menu bar unless it is visible.  It is visible by default."

This is clearly why, but I still don't have a solution to the actual problem. Thanks!

Comment: In full-screen mode you can show MenuBar by moving the cursor to the top edge of the screen.

Comment: Thanks, I have actually used a mac before. That's not the answer to the question I was asking. I need to programmatically disable my menu bar application from opening if the menu bar is hidden due to some application being fullscreened.

Comment: I don't know how you show your app, but if it is the icon in MenuBar I can always make MenuBar appear and then tap on it.

Comment: There is a global key command that I use as an alternate way to toggle the popover being visible. Also, if the user opens the popover and then moves the mouse away, the menu bar disappears but my app's popover window remains.

Comment: For dismissing `NSPopover` when your window loses focus you can set at appearance `NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)`, and `popover.behavior = .transient`. Then your `NSPopover` will be hidden when the user taps outside of your app.

Comment: This is a workaround, but not the correct fix to the problem. How do I completely observe another app entering fullscreen, is really the problem. Thank you for the help though, it is an improvement.

Comment: I would also like to observe and respond to switching desktops or the "view all windows" gesture (four fingers up). Right now the popover simply remains open, which is not ideal...